# uf-cma and uf-cmva probabilistic MAC

Tags: mac, chosen-plaintext-attack

Is there any simple probabilistic MAC $\Pi=(\operatorname{Gen},\operatorname{Tag},\operatorname{Vrfy})$ with UF-CMA security but without UF-CMVA security?

How can an attacker efficiently use the $\operatorname{Vrfy}(\cdot,\cdot)$ algorithm to break the MAC scheme?

Paula

Comment: An example (though not simple) can be found [in this paper](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2011/66320007/66320007.pdf). Also, it is possible to transform any $\text{UF-CMA}$ scheme into a $\text{UF-CMVA}$ scheme, as described [in this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/059.pdf). Unfortunately, I'm not sure there's an intuitive "toy" example that might explain how to use $\text{Vrfy(.,.)}$ to break the scheme, though perhaps it may help to think of this is an analogue to a adaptive chosen ciphertext attack.